# Are hardware components in ros2_control designed to include a ROS 2 node as a member?

Tags: ros2-control, ros2-controllers

I need to transmit high-level status updates strings about my hardware to another node using a publisher. Recognizing that blocking calls are not welcome within the read/write methods, I intend to employ a Node in conjunction with RealtimePublisher from the realtime_tools package. However, I'm uncertain whether it is possible to instantiate a node within the implementation of the SystemInterface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but not recommended if you need to satisfy real-time requirements.
See e.g. [this package](https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/topic_based_ros2_control) (be aware, that was written for simulation).